# How best to do row operations in R

Tags: r, dplyr, row

Below is the sample data

```
   year <- c (2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021)
  indcode <- c(71,71,71,71,71,71,72,72,72,72,72,72,44,44,44,44,44,44,45,45,45,45,45,45)
  avgemp <- c(44,46,48,50,55,56,10,11,12,13,14,15,21,22,22,23,25,25,61,62,62,63,69,77)
  ownership <-c(50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50)

  test3 <- data.frame (year,indcode,avgemp,ownership)
```

The desired result is to have where it sums the avgemp for two specific combinations (71+72 and 44+45) and produces one additional row per year.  The items in the parentheses (below) are just there to illustrate which numbers get added. The primary source of my confusion is how to have it select and therefore add certain indcode combinations. My initial thought is that you would pivot wider, add the columns, and the pivot_longer but hoping for something a bit less convoluted.

```
  year     indcode        avgemp          ownership
  2016       71+72         54 (44+10)         50
  2016         71          44                 50
  2016         72          10
  2017       71+72         57 (46+11)         50
  2018       71+72         60 (48+12)         50
  2019       71+72         63 (50+13)         50
  2020       71+72         69 (55+14)         50
  2021       71+72         71 (56+15)         50
```

I know that it would start something like this

```
 test3 <- test3 %>% group_by (indcode) %>% mutate("71+72" = (something that filters out 71 and  72)
```

Comment: @akrun. No just 71+72 and 44+45

Comment: Why has 2016 in your expected output `2016         71          44                 50
  2016         72          10`?

Comment: @PaulS, I edited the question. Thinking that I want the indcodes (71 and 72) but also the sum of them to be in the end result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table` - convert the data.frame to 'data.table' with `setDT`, grouped by 'year', 'ownership', and the 'indcode' created by an ifelse/fcase method), get the `sum` of 'avgemp' as a summarised output

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test3)[, .(avgemp = sum(avgemp)), .(year, ownership, 
  indcode = fcase(indcode %in% c(71, 72), '71+72', default = '44+45'))]
```

-output

```
   year ownership indcode avgemp
    <num>     <num>  <char>  <num>
 1:  2016        50   71+72     54
 2:  2017        50   71+72     57
 3:  2018        50   71+72     60
 4:  2019        50   71+72     63
 5:  2020        50   71+72     69
 6:  2021        50   71+72     71
 7:  2016        50   44+45     82
 8:  2017        50   44+45     84
 9:  2018        50   44+45     84
10:  2019        50   44+45     86
11:  2020        50   44+45     94
12:  2021        50   44+45    102
```

Comment: do you know of any sources that can break down this code that you produced. Trying to really understand this and not just copy and paste and be done.

Comment: @TimWilcox I added some description.  Hope it helps

Comment: @TimWilcox you may also read the vignettes of data.table for operations using data.table

Comment: if I had a third grouping (indcodes 48 and 49), how would I add that into the code that you provided?

Comment: @TimWilcox you can add `fcase(indcode %in% c(71, 72), '71+72', indcode %in% c(48, 49), '48+49', default = '44+45'))`

Answer (score 1):

```
  group_by(year, gr = indcode %/%10) %>%
   summarise(indcode = paste(unique(indcode), collapse = '+'),
             avgemp = sum(avgemp), ownership = ownership[1], .groups = 'drop') %>%
   select(-gr)%>%
   arrange(indcode)

# A tibble: 12 x 4
    year indcode avgemp     ownership
   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>          <dbl>
 1  2016 44+45       82             50
 2  2017 44+45       84             50
 3  2018 44+45       84             50
 4  2019 44+45       86             50
 5  2020 44+45       94             50
 6  2021 44+45      102             50
 7  2016 71+72       54             50
 8  2017 71+72       57             50
 9  2018 71+72       60             50
10  2019 71+72       63             50
11  2020 71+72       69             50
12  2021 71+72       71             50
```